# Trigger points for javascript depending on viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset, viewport

So, I'm coding up a site that has certain events triggering as you scroll down the page. I want the events to be triggered when the relevant element hits a point just around a quarter of the way down the viewport.

However, this trigger point is obviously different for different sized viewports. I've worked out how to get this trigger point calculated, but I haven't found a way to get the position of a div relative to the top of the viewport/page.

I am trying to use .offset(), which I could combine with getPageScroll() to find the right point, but I can't figure out what on earth to do with the array that it returns. I've also tried popping it in a variable and using that with the syntax I have below (as used on the jquery.com documentation), but it's patently wrong, and returned Undefined in the console.

I am pretty new to both Javascript and jQuery, and to any actual programming in general, so please excuse any stupidity. If I'm doing this all backwards, that's totally a valid answer too! Please just point me in the correct direction if that's the case.

I've coded it up like this so far. The actual effects are only placeholders for now - I'm just trying to get the basic framework working:

```
// getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com - adapted to only return yScroll
function getPageScroll() {
    var yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    return yScroll
}

// Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
function getPageHeight() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return windowHeight
}



var containers = $('div.container');
var element_1 = $('#part_one');
var element_2 = $('#part_two_1');
var element_3 = $('#part_two_2');
var element_4 = $('#part_two_3');
var element_5 = $('#part_two_4');
var element_6 = $('#part_three');
var element_7 = $('#part_four');
var element_8 = $('#part_five');

var docHeight = $(document).height();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var offset = offset();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    var pageBottom = getPageScroll() + getPageHeight(); 

    var quarterPoint = getPageScroll()+((pageBottom-getPageScroll())/4)
    var halfwayPoint = getPageScroll()+((pageBottom-getPageScroll())/2)
    var threeQuarterPoint = pageBottom-((pageBottom-getPageScroll())/4)
    var triggerPoint = quarterPoint-(getPageHeight/10)

    if (triggerPoint < element_1.offset.top){

        containers.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "white", color: "#aaa"}, 50);
        element_1.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#ffa531", color: "white"}, 300, function(){
            $(this).children().stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 300);
        });


    };

    if (triggerPoint > element_2.offset.top){

        containers.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "white", color: "#aaa"}, 50);
        element_2.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#d900ca", color: "white"}, 300, function(){
            $(this).children('img').stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 300);
        });


    };

    if (triggerPoint > element_3.offset(top)){

        containers.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "white", color: "#aaa"}, 50);
        element_3.stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#d900ca", color: "white"}, 300);


    };
```

and so on and so forth, for somewhere between 8 and 12 trigger points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things i see here:

```
var offset = offset(); // i don't believe this is a global function.

if (triggerPoint < element_1.offset.top) { // offset needs to be offset(), its a function not a property
```